# How to go directly to Edit mode in PowerApps Form attached to SharePoint List?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-form, modern-experience, powerapp

I have a PowerApps Form attached to my SharePoint List.

Is there a way for the user to go directly to the Form's Edit mode when double-clicking on the list item?

By default, the Form opens in View mode, and the user then has to click "Edit All" to make changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow below steps:

1. Go to SharePoint list and select **PowerApps --> Customize forms** from top ribbon. It will redirect you to PowerApps studio.
2. After form opens, select **SharePointIntegration** from left side **Tree View** panel.
3. Click on **Advanced** from the right side panel of **SharePointIntegration**.
4. In **OnView** action, Enter `EditForm(SharePointForm1)`. This is in format of `EditForm(YourFormName)`.
5. Save & Publish the form.

Comment: Perfect!  Not sure why I didn't think of this :)