# How to go directly to Edit mode in PowerApps Form attached to SharePoint List without losing the Save and Cancel buttons?

Tags: powerapps-forms

If I follow the steps suggested in [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/275071/how-to-go-directly-to-edit-mode-in-powerapps-form-attached-to-sharepoint-list/283101?noredirect=1#comment301692_283101) post my form itself does indeed open in Edit mode however the integrated Sharepoint buttons act as if they're still in view mode. For example, if I double click an item in the list it opens the form in Edit mode but the buttons at the top do not show Save and Cancel as they normally would if I were in Edit mode, they show Edit All.

How do I make the Save and Cancel buttons show up by default without having to click Edit All?