# Embedded PowerApps form on SharePoint page - How to default to Edit Mode

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-pages, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

I need to embed a powerapps form on a different modern page.  What I'd like is for the user to be able to navigate to this page and have the form open and ready to fill out.  So I embedded the form using the PowerApps webpart successfully, but I need the form to default to Edit Mode, rather than have the user click the "+" symbol to navigate to Edit Mode.  Can anyone please tell me how I can have this web part/form default to Edit Mode?

Thanks!

Chris

Answer (score 0):

How did you set your form? If the form is set to be in edit mode by default, the embeded web part shall also make the form to be in edit mode.

Reference which may be helpful:
[How to go directly to Edit mode in PowerApps Form attached to SharePoint List?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/275071/how-to-go-directly-to-edit-mode-in-powerapps-form-attached-to-sharepoint-list)

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/controls/control-form-detail

Comment: I don't have it set to edit mode by default.  How can I do that?  I'm kind of new to PowerApps.

Comment: @Chris, I am not sure how the form is created so only update some docs which may be helpful.